# Mongoid embedded document returning empty for queries

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

When I query the embedded model, no records are returned despite there being plenty of parent records containing instances of the embedded model.

There are two models, a `Label` embedded in a `Band`:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :label
end

class Label
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :band
end
```

I can query Band (`Band.all`, `Band.find` etc) just fine, but when I query Label, it returns nothing. For instance:

I create the band with the embedded label, and save it:

```
 > b = Band.create
 => #<Band _id: 516cff525543d8842e000008, _type: nil>
 > b.build_label name: "new label"
 => #<Label _id: 516cff5a5543d8842e000009, _type: nil, name: "new label">
 > b.save
 => true
```

Then I query the Band model, and all is fine:

```
 > Band.all.to_a
 => [#<Band _id: 516cff525543d8842e000008, _type: nil>]
 > Band.count
 => 1
 > Band.first.label
 => #<Label _id: 516cff5a5543d8842e000009, _type: nil, name: "new label">
 > Band.find "516cff525543d8842e000008"
 => #<Band _id: 516cff525543d8842e000008, _type: nil>
```

But when I query the Label model, nothing shows up!

```
 > Label.all.to_a
 => []
 > Label.count
 => 0
 > Label.last
 => nil
 > Label.first
 => nil
 > Label.find "516cff5a5543d8842e000009" # this is the label id from Band
 => nil
```

I'm almost positive this is not intended behavior. The code is directly from an example on the Mongoid docs here: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_one

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mongo your queries always target collections, i.e. full documents that may embed other documents. For mongo it's just one big JSON/BSON document. Now, `Label.all` or `Label.all` are equivalent to querying the `Label` collection. Since labels are not stored in the `Label` collection, those queries return nothing. However, you can still query labels on the `Band` collection by calling

```
Band.where(:'labels._id' => "516cff5a5543d8842e000009")
```

or something like

```
Band.where(:'labels.name' => "rock")
```

This is fine if you want to get all bands with a certain label. Getting all labels this way, however, is very expensive and not recommended. What's your main use case? If it is showing labels for a band or getting bands with a certain label, then embedding is great. Otherwise, you could use relations (has_many/belongs_to), or denormalize completely, i.e. save labels within bands and in a separate collection at the same time (leading to redundant data).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I didn't have a particular use case, I just noticed it and thought it was strange behavior -- shouldn't Mongoid at least throw a warning when you do a query on an embedded Mongoid model?

Comment: @SherwinYu, you're right in that it is unintuitive even if it is understandable. Unfortunately, this is the case for many (uncommon) corners of Mongoid, so beware :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use has_many, has_one, belongs_to methods for making possible to run queries as you want like Label.count.

When you embed document into another document it will become as a part(serialized property) of a document. If you want to select labels you should find Band at first and then check the label property. It should definitely work.

Comment: Are you sure? It just seems very unintuitive for that NOT to be the default behavior, even for embedded documents.